# Segmentation fault with glGetObjectLabel

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to retreive a label with [glGetObjectLabel](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glObjectLabel.xhtml). However, I get a segmentation fault. This is my code:

```
const unsigned int size {GL_MAX_LABEL_LENGTH};
char label[size];
GLsizei len[size];
glGetObjectLabel(m_identifier, m_name, size, len, label);
```

What's the problem? [Here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetObjectLabel#Errors) it states *"If not NULL, length​ and label​ should be addresses to which the client has write access, otherwise undefined behavior, including process termination may occur."*
So I guess something is wrong with my *label* and *len* variables.

**EDIT**: m_name was not set to a valid name. I did not know that this would result in a segmentation fault.

Comment: Did you check if `glGetObjectLabel` is a valid function pointer? Or if it might be null? This is a GL 4.3 call, so if you don't have support for that version, and use something like GLEW to get function pointers, the function pointer might be null.

Comment: @Reto Koradi: I have OpenGL 4.5, but how can I check it anyways?

Comment: Look at it in a debugger. Or print it out with something like `printf("glGetObjectLabel = %p\n", glGetObjectLabel)`.

Comment: @Reto Koradi: glGetObjectLabel = 0x7f022dcc4100, so I guess that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

The code has a couple of problems with the arguments of `glGetObjectLabel()`. Primarily, `GL_MAX_LABEL_LENGTH` is the enum value used to retrieve the maximum label length, not the actual maximum label length. Also, the 4th argument is just a pointer to a single value of type `GLsizei`, not an array.

The whole thing should look like this:

```
GLint maxLabelLen = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_LABEL_LENGTH, &maxLabelLen);
GLchar label[maxLabelLen];
GLsizei labelLen = 0;
glGetObjectLabel(m_identifier, m_name, maxLabelLen, &labelLen, label);
```

This would not explain a crash, though. Looks like you figured that part out in the meantime. Passing an invalid value for the second argument should not cause a crash though either. That looks like a driver bug. The call should fail with a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I will implement them like you suggested! I have the OpenGL 4.5 drivers for Linux, maybe those were rushed for release.

Comment: Hm, are variable length arrays allowed?